# Google Maps clustering if markers greater than 5

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add clusters into google map and below code works charm, but I need to add clusters if there are more than 5 markers at same place. How would I do that with `MarkerClusterer`?

```
   function map(data, baseLat, baseLng){
      var markers = [];
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(baseLat, baseLng),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
    
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    
          $.each(data, function(i, val) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(val.property.lat, val.property.lng),
                 //map: map,
                 title: "Title"
              });
    
              markers.push(marker);
    
      });
    
   new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MarkerClustererPlus documentation](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html)

> **minimumClusterSize** number
>
> The minimum number of markers needed in a cluster
>    before the markers are hidden and a cluster marker appears.  The default value is `2`.

To set it to `5`:

```
new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {minimumClusterSize: 5, imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
```

Answer (score 1):

[MarkerClustererPlus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/markerclustererplus) has been refactored into [@googlemaps/markerclusterer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/markerclusterer).

To set the minimum cluster size in the new library, options can be passed to constructor.

Source: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer/issues/111

```
import {MarkerClusterer, SuperClusterAlgorithm} from '@googlemaps/markerclusterer';

new MarkerClusterer({
  algorithm: new SuperClusterAlgorithm({minPoints: 1234}),
})
```